# JQuery ajax not working when sending file value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send file value to PHP with the ajax code below, the file is getting uploaded successfully and stored in the database but the problem is that I get redirected.

```
// submit form data
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    var file = $("#imgInp").get(0).files[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            fname: $('#fname').val(),
            lname: $('#lname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            pass: $('#myPass').val(),
            rights: $(".rights:checked").val(),
            imgInp: file,
            userID: $('#userID').val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: because you are submitting the form with 'submit'

Comment: @vinayakj: That is an event handler and returning `false` should prevent the default action.

Comment: try `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`

Comment: The form is submitting normally, rather than with ajax. This is evident because of the redirect and the file being uploaded(since that ajax code cannot upload a file)

Comment: Post a minimal example of the problem. You might find the solution along the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax upload file with id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319580/jquery-ajax-upload-file-with-id)

Comment: adding event.preventDefault() did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            var file_data = $('#imgInp').prop('files')[0];
            var fname = $('#fname').val();
            var lname = $('#lname').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var pass = $('#myPass').val();
            var rights = $(".rights:checked").val();
            var userID = $('#userID').val();

            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            form_data.append('fname', fname);
            form_data.append('lname', lname);
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            form_data.append('email', email);
            form_data.append('pass', pass);
            form_data.append('rights', rights);
            form_data.append('userID', userID);

            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                data: form_data,
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```